# Buscar e imprimir en consola datos desde un .txt en C#

Tags: c#, archivo, visual-studio-2017

Hola :) Bueno es un programa sencillo en el que se maneja un .txt, el programa tiene la opción de ingresar datos, imprimirlos y buscar....

Mi problema es en la tercera parte: Buscar, los datos que se guardan en el txt son: Clave, Nombre y Puesto de la siguiente manera:

> **123
>  Carlos Dayan Rodriguez Perez
>  Administrador
>
>   -Espacio-
>  234
>  Diego Antonio Rodriguez Perez
>  Programador
>
>   -Espacio-
>  456
>  Juan Camaney
>  Tester
>
>   -Espacio-**

Noten que dice -Espacio- con eso indico que en vez de un salto de linea vació cada que termina un "registro" hay un espacio, ya viene el porque de esto......

El código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Programa1_Agenda
{
    class Program
    {
        static StreamReader Leer;
        static StreamWriter Escribir;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int Op;
            int op_1 = 0;
            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("AGENDA 2018\n\n");
                Console.WriteLine("1) Ingresar datos\n2) Mostrar datos\n3) Buscar persona\n4) Salir\n\nTu opcion: ");
                Op = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (Op == 1)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        int DUI;
                        string nombre;
                        string puesto;
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Escribir un nuevo registro\n\n");
                        Escribir = new StreamWriter("Archivo_Agenda.txt", true);
                        //INGRESA DATOS
                        Console.Write("\n* Ingresar nueva clave DUI (3 Digitos enteros): ");
                        DUI = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        Escribir.WriteLine(DUI);
                        Console.Write("\n* Ingresar nombre completo: ");
                        nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        Escribir.WriteLine(nombre);
                        Console.Write("\n* Ingresar puesto: ");
                        puesto = Console.ReadLine();
                        Escribir.WriteLine(puesto);
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
                        String Cadena = Console.ReadLine();
                        Escribir.WriteLine(Cadena);
                        Escribir.Close();

                        Console.WriteLine("El registro se ha creado exitosamente.\n\n5) Regresar al menu principal\n6) Ingresar un nuevo usuario");
                        Console.Write("\nTu opcion: ");
                        op_1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    } while (op_1 == 6);
                }

                if (Op == 2)
                {
                    string Linea;
                    int contador = 0;
                    Console.Clear();
                    Leer = new StreamReader("Archivo_Agenda.txt", true);
                    Console.WriteLine("Mostrando todos los registros:\n\n");
                    while((Linea = Leer.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(Linea);
                        contador++;
                    }
                    Leer.Close();

                    Console.WriteLine("\nEl registro se mostro exitosamente.\n\n5) Regresar al menu principal\n");
                    Console.Write("\nTu opcion: ");
                    op_1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }

                if (Op == 3)
                {
                    string Linea;
                    int contador = 0;
                    string result_s;
                    Console.Clear();
                    Leer = new StreamReader("Archivo_Agenda.txt", true);
                    Console.WriteLine("Buscar registro por medio de clave DUI:\n\n");
                    Console.Write("Ingresa la clave DUI: ");
                    result_s = Console.ReadLine();
                    if((Linea = Leer.ReadLine()) == result_s)
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(Linea);
                            contador++;
                        } while ((Linea = Leer.ReadLine()) != " ");
                    }
                    Leer.Close();

                    Console.WriteLine("\nEl registro se mostro exitosamente.\n\n5) Regresar al menu principal\n");
                    Console.Write("\nTu opcion: ");
                    op_1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            } while (op_1 == 5);
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que intento hacer en la opción 3, es que al pedir la clave DUI y ser detectada en el archivo se imprima en pantalla los datos siguientes hasta que se encuentre un espacio (y esta es la razón del porque...)

Esto lo hace con si se ingresa el primer registro: 123, e imprime lo correcto:

**123

Carlos Dayan Rodriguez Perez

Administrador**

Pero si ingreso cualquiera de los otros 2 no se imprime nada... :(

Por favor ayuda, ya no se que hacer xd

Comment: Sólo estas leyendo la primera línea despues de solicitar el dato, es normal que sólo te lea el primer registro
result_s = Console.ReadLine();
if((Linea = Leer.ReadLine()) == result_s)

tras pedir el dato DUI debes hacer un bucle de Leer.ReadLine para que "busque" el dato que pides...a ver si te aclara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muy buenas Carlos,
como bien comenta Raul, el problema es que debes usar un primer bucle  para encontrar la clave(si existe), y una vez encontrada  entonces ya puedes utilizar el bucle que tienes para imprimir por consola la información.

Te dejo un ejemplo de la **Opcion 3** funcionando usando dos bucles `do-while`:

```
   if (Op == 3)
    {
        string Linea;
        int contador = 0;
        string result_s;
        Console.Clear();
        Leer = new StreamReader("Archivo_Agenda.txt", true);
        Console.WriteLine("Buscar registro por medio de clave DUI:\n\n");
        Console.Write("Ingresa la clave DUI: ");
        result_s = Console.ReadLine();
        do
        {
            Linea = Leer.ReadLine();
        } while (Linea != result_s && Linea!= null);

        if ((Linea == result_s))
        {
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Linea);
                Linea = Leer.ReadLine();

            } while (Linea !=" ");
        }
        Leer.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("\nEl registro se mostro exitosamente.\n\n5) Regresar al menu principal\n");
        Console.Write("\nTu opcion: ");
        op_1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

Comment: Vaya muchas gracias, nunca la pensé así no pude verlo.... aun soy un novato :) pero enserio muchas gracias